# Plot multiple datasets from one file

Tags: gnuplot

Note: I can control the format of the data file, but it has to be a single file.

I'm trying to plot multiple datasets on the same graph using gnuplot. I'd like ideally to plot something like this:

```
data_1 0 0
data_2 0 0
data_1 1 1
data_2 0 1
data_1 2 2
data_2 1 2
```

And so on. In this case, `data_1` and `data_2` should be two separate curves.

I'd also like to avoid putting in the gnuplot script the list, or even the number, of possible datasets. Basically, I'd like it to "group" data points by a specific field, and plot each group as a separate dataset on the same graph.

As a last-resort alternative, I could split the original file into one file per dataset using grep, and plot those (I guess it's easier?), but I'm looking for a way to do it with a single file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The gnuplot-way to save your data would be to separate the data sets with *two* empty lines. Then you can use `index` to access the different data sets in the single file:

```
data_1 0 0
data_1 1 1
data_1 2 2


data_2 0 0
data_2 0 1
data_2 1 2
```

And plot that with

```
plot 'file.dat' using 2:3 index 0, '' using 2:3 index 1
```

To get the number of data sets, use the `stats` command which saves the number of data sets (data blocks) in a variable which you can use for iterating:

```
stats 'file.dat' using 0 nooutput
plot for [i=0:(STATS_blocks - 1)] 'file.dat' using 2:3 index i
```

To extend this, you could even format your file as follows

```
data_1
0 0
1 1
2 2


data_2
0 0
0 1
1 2
```

and use the first line of seach data set as plot key:

```
set key autotitle columnheader
stats 'file.dat' using 0 nooutput
plot for [i=0:(STATS_blocks - 1)] 'file.dat' using 1:2 index i
```

[image]

Comment: This is definitely the way to go if the OP can restructure the file (and they did say they are free to do so).  I wanted to answer it using the provided file structure.  This, however, is the easier way when this restructuring is possible.

Comment: I have a very similar issue. I cannot restructure the data that I have. The data sets are separated by one empty line instead of two. Is there a way to tell gnuplot to use one empty line instead of two to separate the data sets? Like we can for the field separators.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an external program to fetch the values from the first column and then conditionally plot the data based on that.

For example, using python3 (and Windows style quotes), we can do<sup>**1**</sup>

```
values = system('python -c "data = sorted(set(x.split()[0] for x in open(\"datafile\",\"r\"))); print(\"\n\".join(data))"')
```

This will cause the variable *values* to contain `"data_1 data_2"`.  Now, we can use `plot for` looping over this variable.  We test each line to see if the first column value is correct.  If it isn't we use the value `1/0` which causes gnuplot to skip that line.

```
plot for [w in values] datafile u 2:((strcol(1) eq w)?$3:1/0) with points pt 7 t w
```

[image]

Of course, this causes discontinuities in the plots.  If we don't want that (for example, using the lines style), we can use an external program to filter.  For example, using awk (with Windows quotes)

```
plot for [w in values] sprintf('< awk "($1==\"%s\")" datafile',w) u 2:3 with lines t w
```

[image]

Here we use `sprintf` to build up redirection commands using awk for the index we are working with:

```
< awk "($1==\"data_1\")" datafile
< awk "($1==\"data_2\")" datafile
```

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Using standard unix commands, we also could do (Windows quotes)

```
values = system('awk "{print $1}" datafile | sort | uniq')
```