# Using the same column for muliple lines in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a continuous stream of data in two columns that I am trying to plot. The data contains different trajectories however, and I want gnuplot to plot theses with lines but not connect the different trajectories. How would I signal gnuplot to recognize these different trajectories and not connect them?

Eg:

```
1 1
2 4
3 9
new traj
1 1
2 .5
3 .333
```

Sorry if this has been posted before, I searched for about an hour and gave up. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would need two blank lines between your data sets, and you would need to comment out the heading (`# new traj`). If that is possible, have a look and the index directive.

Comment: That worked great.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35785030/2604213